# Creating content slider that works only on small screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to create image slider that works only when screen size is smaller then 640 pixels. When screen is wider then 640 it show 3 items with 33% width so it fits nice on the screen. I achieved to make them slide but if i re size back to larger then 640 pixels and clear Interval the slider just freezes and leaves me distorted 3 pictures. Is there any way to make slider work only on one screen size? The below code is what i got so far, but i just heaven't found any similar task, or seen anyone do it on the google.

***Jquery Code***

```
 var slider = $("#slider")
    var container = $("#slides");
    var slides = $(".slides");
    var len = 3;
    var current = 1;
    var width = '100%';
    var animationSpeed = 3000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var interval;

    function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
                container.animate({
                    'margin-left': '-=' + width
                }, animationSpeed, function () {
                    if (++current === len) {
                        current = 1;
                        container.css('margin-left', 0);
                    }
                });
            }, pause);
    }

    function stopSlider(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    function checkView() {
        var winWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
        if(winWidth < 640   ) {
           startSlider();
        } else{

            stopSlider();
        }

    }
    checkView();
    $(window).resize(checkView);
```

**Html Code**

```
<section id="slider" class="slider clearfix">
       <nav class="nav-arrow">
           <img id="#prev" class="prev" src="images/1463330656_br_prev.png" alt="prev">
           <img id="#next" class="next" src="images/1463330669_br_next.png" alt="next">
       </nav>
     <ul id="slides" class="slides">
         <li><img class="slide" src="images/box.jpg" alt=""></li>
         <li><img class="slide" src="images/bridge.jpg" alt=""></li>
         <li><img class="slide" src="images/smile.jpg" alt=""></li>
     </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: if you want the slider to work both on phone/mobile device and on desktop  take a look at the source of this page http://musicmatters.ie/gallery.html. it has a couple of helpful jquery gallery-helper scripts. Worth a look. jquery.wmuSlider.js and jquery.wmuGallery.js

Answer (score 0):

You should really resize the content or 'CheckView' according to css media queries as opposed to hard coding sizes into your jquery.

You can have several media queries appended to the end of your css, where you can adjust the size accordingly, e.g.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:640px){ // your necessary css here}
 @media only screen and (min-width:1024px){ // your necessary css here}
```

note: these are just examples

Comment: I'm resizeing with media queries, but slider works in jquery. Question is not   about styling but about the slideing effect when screen is smaller or larger.
Did you even ran into a plugin or slider that works that way?

Comment: do you want the slider to run on a desktop too, ideally?

Comment: No...just on small screen, on desktop should look like three column layout
look at this codepen http://codepen.io/Kyokotsu/pen/pymgwK